# alternative to IN clause SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I am running the following query which is taking too much time:

```
select a.id, b.name 
from temp.dbo.COLD a with (NOLOCK)
inner join temp.dbo.FIVE b with (NOLOCK)
on a.id = b.cid
where a.proc_flag ='C'
and b.dt >= dateadd(D,-(cast('60' as int)),cast(GETDATE() as date))
and b.cCode in 
(
'ADC',
'BUNE',
'DD',
'HUUP',
'INER',
'MNER',
'NCIT',
'NOG',
'TRON',
'WRUM',
'XFNA',
'BL', 
'DIO', 
'DOM', 
'HU',
'ILL',
'INKT',
'LB',
'NOM',
'PE',
'RF',
'SE',
'XER',
'Pge',
'dd',
'CC');
```

let me know if I can use something else instead of IN clause.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: is there another value in the b table that can define these cCode values that can be used in an exists clause

Comment: Check indexes on your temp tables. The problem seems to be there and not in your usage of `IN`

Comment: Also write `declrare @d date = dateadd(D,-60,cast(GETDATE() as date))` and then `and b.dt >= d`. Such code will evaluate date only once.

Comment: @kpa6uk: any code will evaluate GETDATE only once, no matter how you write your query. `GETDATE` a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx).

Comment: @RemusRusanu thanks for this knowledge piece. However personally I think this action will improve readability of this code.

Answer (score 3):

*Join* vs *temporary table* with the values you want to compare. That allows more query optimizations. Make sure the temp table has an index with statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure and find the bottleneck. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/). SQL performance is not driven by how you write the text, the optimizer will reinterpret it anyway how ti sees fit. Is all about what data access path alternatives exists. In other words: **indexes**.

Post your complete and exact data model. Post you data cardinality (table sizes).

[NOLOCK results are incorrect results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

My 8-ball tells me you need:

- a (likely clustered) index on `temp.dbo.COLD(id)`
- a clustered index on `temp.dbo.FIVE(dt)`

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select a.id, b.name 
from temp.dbo.COLD a with (NOLOCK) inner join
     temp.dbo.FIVE b with (NOLOCK)
     on a.id = b.cid
where a.proc_flag = 'C' and
      b.dt >= dateadd(D,-(cast('60' as int)),cast(GETDATE() as date)) and
      b.cCode in ( . . . )
```

It is highly unlikely that the list of values in the `in` is strongly related to a performance bottleneck -- other than the fact that they are bringing in more rows to process.  I would propose the following composite indexes:

```
COLD(proc_flag, id)
FIVE(id, dt, cCode, name)
```

These are covering indexes for the query and should help performance.